# Baby Rudin, Theorem 6.10

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Here is a theorem from Rudin:

[image]

My question is this. What if for example $E=\{a\}$? Then $K=\{a\}\cup [u_1,b]$. $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, how can it be continuous on $K$?

Also, just to clarify: to obtain the last inequality, Rudin splits the sum into two sums, one of which being summed over all $j$ for which $x_j=v_k$ for some $k$, right?

Comment: what is $\alpha$ here?

Comment: @Masacroso any strictly monotonically increasing function (from the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a\notin [u_1, b]$, there must be some $\delta > 0$ such that $x\in \{a\}\cup [u_1, b]$ and $\lvert x-a\rvert < \delta$ implies $x = a$ (for example, any $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta < u_1-a$). Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lvert x-a\rvert < \delta$ implies $$\lvert f(x)-f(a)\rvert = 0 < \epsilon$$ as we must have $x = a$. Therefore, if $f$ is continuous on $[u_1, b]$, then $f$ will be continuous on $\{a\}\cup [u_1, b]$.

Comment: Is there any corresponding general version of this statement? Like if a function is discontinuous at some point, then it is continuous at this point when restricted to some smaller domain containing the point of discontinuity as an isolated point?

Comment: This is a topological statement more than anything. For a function $f : X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $f$ is called "continuous" if for any open set $O\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$. Furthermore, $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for every neighborhood $V\ni f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Therefore, if $f$ is *not* continuous at some $x$, all we need to do is choose a topological subspace $S$ of $X$ such that $\{x\}$ is open in $S$ (i.e. $x$ is an "isolated point"), and $f|_S : S\to Y$ will be continuous at $x$.